# Python multi-process and multi-threading or single function cost the same time

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to realize a function of finding the password of excel. So i use both `threading` and `Process` to run the codes, but it raise a question the process time is really the same whatever i use 4 threads or 8 threads even i just use the single function to find the password.

Here's my step:

1. the first step to use `itertools` to create password dictionary

   ```
   import itertools,os,time
   from win32com.client import Dispatch
   from multiprocessing import Process
   import threading
   import pywintypes
   import pythoncom
   time_begin = time.time()
   # setting the password words
   path='C:/Users/M_Seas/Desktop/file.xlsx'
   words='wulong'
   passw=[]
   pw=itertools.product(words,repeat=6)
   # write all combination into dic and list
   dic=open("password.txt","w")
   for word in pw:
       dic.write(''.join(word)+'\n')
   dic.close()
   with open("password.txt","r") as f:
       for word in f.readlines():
           passw.append(word.strip('\n'))
   ```
2. The next setp is create function `mainstep()` to use combination to open the excel

   ```
   def mainstep(file,passwords):
       pythoncom.CoInitialize()
       excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
       excel.Visible = False
       for password in passwords:
           try:
               excel.Workbooks.Open(file, False, True, None, Password=password)
           except pywintypes.com_error:
               excel.Application.Quit()
               pass
           else:
               print('Success '+password)
               excel.Application.Quit()
               time_end=time.time()
               print('time:{} seconds '.format(time_end-time_begin))
               break
   ```
3. Finally create the multi-process or multi-threading to speed up

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 10
       groups = [passw[i::NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES] for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES)]
        '''test in two ways'''
   #    for group in groups:
   #        t = threading.Thread(target=mainstep, args=(path,group))
   #        t.start()
       for group in groups:
           p = Process(target=mainstep, args=(path,group))
           p.start()
   ```

I try to set `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 4/8/10`, the process time are all the same whatever i use `threading` or `threading`

I also test just use the `mainstep()` to see the original process time, the time is the same as i use multi-process and multi-threading.

Is there any way can real speed up the process time???

Comment: I suspect that Excel itself may refuse to run several instances in parallel. You can probably check whether that is the issue in the task manager. If so, `unoconv` might be an alternative.

Comment: you may right, Excel only run in serial. i remove the Excel and only output the num the ```Process``` speed up .And what is the function of  lib ```unoconv```? i search for it , ,likely a format converter.

Comment: `unoconv` is a document converter based on Libreoffice. AFAIK, it's one of the few (the only?) independent software that can open password protected excel files. However, I'll have to admit that I _cannot_ promise that it won't suffer from the same limitation.